# C++ Calling a method on an object you only need once

Tags: c++

I can't remember what it is called, but I know i can do it in Java.
Suppose I have the following:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {};
    void bar() {};
};
```

I want to do this:

```
int main() {
    (new Foo).bar();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there a similar way to do this without having to do:

```
int main() {
    Foo foobar;
    foobar.bar();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new` dynamically-allocates memory and returns a pointer. Class members are obtained using the indirection operator `->`. I don't think this is what you're looking for as you run the risk of causing a memory leak. Simply calling the constructor of `Foo` allows us to do what we want:

```
Foo().bar();
```

By calling the constructor of `Foo`, we create a temporary object off of which we can obtain its data members. This is preferred over pointers as we don't have to deal with memory leaks and deletion of the pointer.

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that declaring a variable also initializes it. Weird.

Comment: @Coolguy123, Only when it has a nontrivial constructor. `int` would still be left uninitialized.

Comment: @David: You probably hit the 200 rep limit cap.

Comment: @JesseGood I made 245 rep before answering. Is that too much?

Comment: Yes, you can only get up to 200 rep in 24 hrs ([reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18404/200-rep-limit-over-what-period-exactly)).

Answer (score 4):

You can say `(new Foo)->bar();`. That works but is absolutely idiotic. The correct thing is this:

```
int main()
{
    Foo x;
    x.bar(); 
}
```

Or, if you don't want the local variable: `Foo().bar();`. But now that's questionable, since if you don't need `Foo` to be stateful, then you probably don't need a class at all. Just make `bar` a **free function** (something that doesn't exist in Java):

```
void bar();

int main()
{
    bar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Foo().bar();`. No need to use `new` like in Java.